# Track a user that is not logged in

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is it possible to track not logged in user without using session or a cookie? Is there a more reliable way?
Just like www.filefactory.com or other similar download space website, they can track if you are free user and send download request, before starting next download you must wait x time, I was thinking it used session or cookies, but after clearing session and cookie or change IP address, it's still the same.

I'm a newbie trying to create a website, I have to track user before logged in like this example site, I'm using php and javascript set session and timeout to keep catch user status (to write file in dir or ...
I've been searching a long time, if anyone knows any tutorial or just a little clue how to do it like this site it would be appreciated..

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer is **NO**, infact how you can even make a login system without SESSIONS?

Comment: Really? Why these website can do it? or did I misunderstanding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You dont track who is not logged in, you track whois logged in. So by default everybody gets the link for you must wait xx amount of seconds. If you clear cookies and start a new session, you are still a default user.

Now when somebody logs in, you can put in the session that he is authenticated. Then on the page to show the link you check that. Now if this logged in user would clear his cookies, he would become a default user again untill he logs in again.

```
//not actual php code
if (authenticated) {
  //show direct download link
} else {
  //show link after xx seconds
}
```

If you dont want to use session to keep track of logged in users, there are other ways, but most often its not realy needed or even less secure. Another way could be to use the `authenticate header` or keep the information in the query string. Both are less secure in my opion, but could be used.

Now if the goal is to prevent free users from downloading two files and need to wait for the second link, you can also make an educated guess if its the same user by combining user information to some sort of hash. EG user-agent, ip-address, location. This will not be 100% accurate, but could give you some idea of a returning free user without sessions.

Comment: Wow, so what we can use to an educated guess is: 1. session 2. cookie  3. ip-address 4. and browser info like http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/ . any other more?

Comment: A session/cookies isnt realy a guess. But it can be cleared. For guesing you use information from the client that isnt always available and could be shared by multiple people. Like IP adres can be used by more then one person. Also more people share a user-agent if the use the same browser. And also more people live in a certain area. Combining all those things however will make the amount of people that match smaller. The more data, the more precise. Try a `print_r($_SERVER)` to see a lot of possible options. But remember > its always a GUESS and never certain you have the same user.

Comment: Also keep in mind that most of those sites are trying to block out the majority of the users. EG the regular, none technical users that just want a quick download. Somebody that realy wants that second link to appear directly without paying and has some knowledge, can bypass the waiting time without doubt.