# Track non registered users

Tags: php, user-registration

I had already gone through similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519891/track-a-user-that-is-not-logged-in), but those does not answer my question.

I have a weird scenario.
In my application (which is fundraising application) there are two types of users.

1. Registered users
2. Non registered users

Both types of users can pay with PayPal. I need to restrict both types of users so they can't pay more than FOUR time to the same fundraiser. Registered users can be restricted and its quite clear, but how I can restrict non registered users ? Thoughts  ?

Comment: Uhm, using their paypal info?

Comment: So what data are you proposing to use to tag/track non-registered users?  A cookie? IP Address? email address used for paypal submission?

Comment: Not sure, as Cookies and IP address can be changed

Comment: Do you have a DB setup?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I have, but there is an option that users can pay/donate with out registration and I called these non registered users

Comment: Then track the times they've clicked your link and setup a restriction column. Once it hits `4` then they can't donate anymore, using an `if` condition.

Comment: @Fred-ii- But how I can know its the same user ?

Comment: If you have an `id` or `user` column, then you can use that to know if it's the same user. As for unregistered users, would be a different ball of wax. You'd need a cookie for them, best I can come up with, but then again cookies can always be deleted. You could track their IP but that can also change, so it's a `catch-22` scenario.

Comment: Can you use a callback from Paypal to prevent the transaction going through? What Paypal products have you looked at to accomplish this?

Comment: I am using PayPal adaptive payments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PayPal [IPN services](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside). IPN return all the required information which also consists email address, based on that email address you can keep track of non-registered users.